# Tzscan API not responsive

Tags: tzscan, api

I have an issue with API requests from tzscan. When calling delegator_rewards in my PHP script, for instance:

```
https://api6.tzscan.io/v3/delegator_rewards/KT1ALgpzePTQPsmbtybBhC3Kg6RNK8gTXUQi
```

then outputs often do not show up. I've tested with several delegator-addresses in a browser and often only after several reloads the API call shows results. This behaviour makes it difficult to use delegator_rewards in a PHP script.

For reference, I performed a simple test and counted the time I needed to reload the browser with the above quoted URL until I got a response: I had to reload the page 7 times until I got a response. 6 times I immediately received a blank screen and the 7th time the outputs were loaded with the response time being around 2 seconds.

How should this API be called in a PHP script to be more responsive?

Comment: Would be useful if you could perform some measurements and provide the statistics to quantify your question more

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand your comment. How can I perform such measurements?

Comment: you want to record the time your browser emitted the request and the time you got your response. You could compare this to the ping response time to assess tzscan internal latency ?

Comment: Ok, will try that and then improve the question.

Comment: Tzscan does not seem to respond to ping requests: "ping: cannot resolve https://tzscan.io: Unknown host". I improved the answer with your first suggestion though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because tzscan is not operating any more as a tezos block explorer